# Java text extraction and data structure design

Tags: java, python, serialization, data-structures, text-extraction

I have a huge set of data of **tables in Open Office 3.0 document format**.

```
   Table 1:
    (x range)|(x1,y1) |(x2,y2)|(x3,x3)|(x4,y4) 
    (-20,90) |(-20,0) |(-5,1) |(5,1)  |(10,0)
    ...
```

Like wise i have n number of tables.All of these tables are fuzzy set membership functions.In simple terms they are computational model's according to which i have to process the input data.There are many number of such tables with differing row size and column size 3/4 .These data's are not going to change once loaded.

**Example:**
When i get a value of x in between the range -20 to 90.I will apply the first rule(given above).Suppose that it is -1(which is in between value of -20 and -5).Then I have to find a corresponding value between 0 and 1.

My **First question** is how to extract all the data from the tables in document format so that i can use in my java program.I know a bit of python and I know python can be useful in such cases.But then how to use it in my Java program.

**Secondly** what would be the best data structure i should use in such a senario.

**Note:** I'm not using any database.So i would prefer to keep the tables either in xml or some other format so that i can load it easily to the program.I also thinking of making a suitable data structure and then serializing them so that I can load them whenever required instead of parsing a file and recreating the data structure.Please post your comments.

Comment: @All - please read the comments to other answers, the question is not about parsing the formatted table in text format.

Comment: @Andreas:I have mentioned it above the table.May be you missed it.I'll highlight it for you.

Comment: *document format* doesn't indicate that you have an OpenOffice Document (which version?) that holds the data. So the task is *not* parsing the example text but extracting data from an OpenOffice document. That was my concern.

Comment: @Andreas:Sorry for the misunderstanding I caused.I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to parse an OpenOffice Document in Java (to extract data), you can use a dedicated API such as [ODFDOM](http://odftoolkit.org/projects/odfdom/pages/Home).
I think this solution is very complicated for what you need. A easier solution would be to extract manually the OpenOffice table, to put it in a format more friendly to parse in Java:

- CSV
- DataBase (MySQL, etc.)

Comment: +1 for the practical advise: copy and paste the table to a spreadsheet and export the table data from there to csv. Makes life much easier.

Comment: Thanks.It helped and for the data structure I decided to use navigable map.
check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519901/get-values-for-keys-within-a-range-in-java