# Get values for keys within a range in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, range-map

Suppose I have a map in Java which looks like this:

```
{ 
 39:"39 to 41",
 41:"41 to 43",
 43:"43 to 45",
 45:">=45"
}
```

If the keys are in sorted order(either using treemap or linkedhashmap).Now if i try to get a value which is >=39 and <41.Then I should get the String "39 to 41".How do I do this efficiently?

Comment: You mean `<= 41` I guess. But will you always look for `39,41,43,45` or should it work if you try with ex `40,42,50`? And is there always only one in between?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data structures that can map a range of keys to a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399821/data-structures-that-can-map-a-range-of-keys-to-a-value)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It looks like you want more than a [`SortedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html); you want a [`NavigableMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html)! Specifically you can use the [`floorKey`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#floorKey%28K%29) operation.

Here's an example:

```
    NavigableMap<Integer,String> map =
        new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

    map.put(0, "Kid");
    map.put(11, "Teens");
    map.put(20, "Twenties");
    map.put(30, "Thirties");
    map.put(40, "Forties");
    map.put(50, "Senior");
    map.put(100, "OMG OMG OMG!");

    System.out.println(map.get(map.floorKey(13)));     // Teens
    System.out.println(map.get(map.floorKey(29)));     // Twenties
    System.out.println(map.get(map.floorKey(30)));     // Thirties
    System.out.println(map.floorEntry(42).getValue()); // Forties
    System.out.println(map.get(map.floorKey(666)));    // OMG OMG OMG!
```

Note that there are also `ceilingKey`, `lowerKey`, `higherKey`, and also `…Entry` instead of `…Key` operations as well which returns a `Map.Entry<K,V>` instead of just the `K`.

Comment: I didn't know this, and apparently neither did anybody here. Very cool!

Comment: All hail the standard runtime!

Comment: At times I feel like I know Java, and then I run into something like this and my mind is blown away.

Comment: Minor quibble with a good solution, but `map.floorEntry(13).getValue()` feels a little cleaner than `map.get(map.floorKey(13))`.

Answer (score 7):

Try Java 6 `java.util.NavigableMap`. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html.

In special use `floorKey`/`floorEntry`.

By example: `floorKey(40)` should return `39`. floorEntry would return the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

With a sorted map, you could do something like that:

```
SortedMap<Integer,String> head = map.headMap(value+1);
if (head.isEmpty()) {
    return null;
} else {
    return head.get(head.lastKey());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's going to be easy. One suggestion would be to "fill in the gaps", ie put in a value `40->"39 to 41"` etc etc. I suppose that will only be possible if you know the whole range of numbers possible in the map.

Or mabybe something that overrides the `get` to check to see if the value is in the map, and expanding out until it finds something. I'm not sure that's going to be possible in its current guise, as you'd have to end up parsing the value strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively look for lower boundary.

```
public String descriptionFor(int value) {
    String description = map.get(value);
    return description == null ? descriptionFor(value--) : description;
}
```

You will need to have a minimum boundary.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to implement such a map yourself, I believe.  You're right that it would have to be sorted; the implementation of `get` would have to iterate through the keys until it finds the largest key that is less than or equal to the argument.

If you subclass `TreeMap` it would initially appear that you can get this working via simply overriding the `get()` method.  However, to maintain as much of the Map contract as possible you'll have to override other methods for consistency.

And what about e.g. `containsKey()`?  Does your main contain a mapping for `40`?  If you return `false`, then a client can decide not to call `get()` based on this information; for these reason (and the formal definition) you have to return `true`.  But then it makes it hard to determine whether the map "really contains" a given mapping; if you're looking to do something such as update without overwriting anything that already exists.

The `remove()` method might be tricky too.  From my reading of the interface,

```
// Calling map.remove "Removes the mapping for a key from this map if it is present."
map.remove(x);

// Now that the mapping is removed, I believe the following must hold
assert map.get(x) == null;
assert map.containsKey(x);
```

Acting consistently here would be *very* tricky.  If you have a mapping from 35-40 for example, and you call `remove(38)`, then as I understand it you'd have to return `null` for any subsequent gets for the key 38, but return the aforementioned mapping for keys 35-37 or 39-40.

---

So while you can make a start on this by overriding TreeMap, perhaps the whole concept of `Map` is not quite what you want here.  Unless you need this behaviour to slot into existing methods that take `Map`, it might be easier to create it yourself as a distinct class since it's not *quite* a Map, the way you're defining it.