# How to convert a Navigablemap to String[][]

Tags: java, string, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I need to convert a navigable map to a 2D String array.  Below given is a code from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519901/get-values-for-keys-within-a-range-in-java/3520271#3520271) to one of my previous question.

```java
NavigableMap<Integer,String> map =
        new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

map.put(0, "Kids");
map.put(11, "Teens");
map.put(20, "Twenties");
map.put(30, "Thirties");
map.put(40, "Forties");
map.put(50, "Senior");
map.put(100, "OMG OMG OMG!");

System.out.println(map.get(map.floorKey(13)));     // Teens
System.out.println(map.get(map.floorKey(29)));     // Twenties
System.out.println(map.get(map.floorKey(30)));     // Thirties
System.out.println(map.floorEntry(42).getValue()); // Forties
System.out.println(map.get(map.floorKey(666)));    // OMG OMG OMG!
```

I have to convert this map to a 2D String array:

```
{
{"0-11","Kids"},
{"11-20","Teens"},
{"20-30","Twenties"}
...
}
```

Is there a fast and elegant way to do this?

Comment: `"OMG OMG OMG!"` - LOL no wonder the snippet looks familiar...

Comment: @poly:have a better solution?

Comment: @Emil: do you have to represent the data as a `String[][]`? What about a generic `List<MappedInterval<Integer,String>>` instead? You can get `MappedInterval.start()` and `.end()`, and `.value()`, and you can `@Override` the `toString()` to print it like `[start-end] => value` or something like that. Basically I don't think you can come up with any much better algorithm to convert to `String[][]`, but there are much better representation than `String[][]` to begin with, and I can give the snippet to do that.

Comment: Actually I wanted to show the map in Jtable.That's why I'm converting it into a 2d array

Comment: @Emil: if you have a look at the quick tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#simple ; they did warn that the simple model using two dimensional arrays have disadvantages. Fortunately you can define your own custom table model that would not require you to create this array, but rather get the data directly from the `NavigableMap`.

Comment: @Emil: it will also make updating the `NavigableMap` much easier in case you want to allow editing.

Comment: I don't have much idea in swing.Thanks for the info.If possible please post a sample for representing the above code in Jtable using tablemodel.

Comment: @Poly:Thanks for your comment's.I implemented the table model by tweaking a bit of this code http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/MapTableModel.htm
along with Marks answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best bet is just to iterate through the Map and create an array for each entry, the troublesome part is generating things like "0-11" since this requires looking for the next highest key...but since the Map is sorted (because you're using a TreeMap) it's no big deal.

```
String[][] strArr = new String[map.size()][2];
int i = 0;
for(Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()){
    // current key
    Integer key = entry.getKey();
    // next key, or null if there isn't one
    Integer nextKey = map.higherKey(key);

    // you might want to define some behavior for when nextKey is null

    // build the "0-11" part (column 0)
    strArr[i][0] = key + "-" + nextKey;

    // add the "Teens" part (this is just the value from the Map Entry)
    strArr[i][1] = entry.getValue();

    // increment i for the next row in strArr
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,it works.I gave a break when nextKey is null.I'll just wait a little while longer and see if any one else gives a better one.

Answer (score 1):

you can create two Arrays, one with the keys and one with the values in an "elegant way" then you can construct an String[][] using this two arrays.

```
// Create an array containing the values in a map 
Integer[] arrayKeys = (Integer[])map.keySet().toArray( new Integer[map.keySet().size()]); 
// Create an array containing the values in a map 
String[] arrayValues = (String[])map.values().toArray( new String[map.values().size()]); 

String[][] stringArray = new String[arrayKeys.length][2];
for (int i=0; i < arrayValues.length; i++)
{
      stringArray[i][0] = arrayKeys[i].toString() + (i+1 < arrayValues.length ? " - " + arrayKeys[i+1] : "");
      stringArray[i][1] = arrayValues[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library:

```java
String[][] array = EntryStream.of(map)
        .pairMap((e1, e2) -> new String[] {
                "%s-%s".formatted(e1.getKey(), e2.getKey()), e1.getValue()})
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature can be used to achieve the desired result:

```java
map.entrySet().stream()
        .gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(2))
        .map(list -> new String[] {
                "%s-%s".formatted(list.get(0).getKey(), list.get(1).getKey()),
                list.get(0).getValue()
        })
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

This uses the new [`Stream.gather`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)) method with the new built-in [`Gatherers.windowSliding`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowSliding(int)) gatherer to convert the map's entry set from `Stream<Entry>` to a pairwise `Stream<List<Entry>>`.  Each of these two-element lists is then transformed to a two-element `String[]` using the existing [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) method.

```
[
  {0: "Kids"},
  {11: "Teens"},
  {20: "Twenties"},
  {30: "Thirties"},
  {40: "Forties"},
  {50: "Senior"},
  {100: "OMG OMG OMG!"}
]

->

[
  [{0: "Kids"}, {11: "Teens"}],
  [{11: "Teens"}, {20: "Twenties"}],
  [{20: "Twenties"}, {30: "Thirties"}],
  [{30: "Thirties"}, {40: "Forties"}],
  [{40: "Forties"}, {50: "Senior"}],
  [{50: "Senior"}, {100: "OMG OMG OMG!"}]
]

->

[
  ["0-11", "Kids"],
  ["11-20", "Teens"],
  ["20-30", "Twenties"],
  ["30-40", "Thirties"],
  ["40-50", "Forties"],
  ["50-100", "Senior"]
]
```

## Javadocs

[`Gatherer`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.

[`Stream.gather`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherers.windowSliding`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowSliding(int))

> Returns a Gatherer that gathers elements into windows -- encounter-ordered groups of elements -- of a given size, where each subsequent window includes all elements of the previous window except for the least recent, and adds the next element in the stream. […]
>
> Example:
>
> ```java
> // will contain: [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8]]
> List<List<Integer>> windows2 =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(2)).toList();
>
> // will contain: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
> List<List<Integer>> windows6 =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).gather(Gatherers.windowSliding(6)).toList();
> ```